# Can't save state of selected columns in log viewer of developer console

Tags: apex, force.com, developer-console

I faced the trouble with developer console when I can't save the state of columns which were selected in log viewer. Actually I open a log in developer console and see the default set of columns
[image]
But I'd like to work with a different set of columns thus I configure columns as I want
[image]
But if I'll load another log than the state of columns will be reset to default state.

I tried to save **current perspective** as well as tried to save and use a **new perspective** but I get the default set of columns in any case after loading new log in the log viewer.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Did you try using a different browser?

Comment: @DashboardReport Yes, I tried Chrome, Firefox and Firefox Developer Edition

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled for your browsers? Could be why the saved state isn't staying.

Comment: @DashboardReport yes, cookies are enabled

Comment: I just tried to remove a column, save the perspective, close the console, and reopen it, and the column reappeared. I'm in the proper view and everything. Looks like its either a bug, or the values just don't pass over between sessions.